# Rescheduling Timer in android

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm trying to have a Timer that schedules a TimerTask for successive executions. I don't know how many times it'll work. on a user click, the Timer will stop, and on another, it'll run again. Everything works until stopping, when i reschedule, I get exceptions saying that the Timer is canceled or already scheduled. How do I make it stop and run again? I've tried everything I could think of and it's still not working.

This is the latest code I'm trying:

```
        Timer myTimer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cameraTimedTask = new camera(this);

        myTimer = new Timer("cameraTimer");

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myTimer.purge();
                myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(cameraTimedTask, 1000, 5000);
            }
        });

        Button bb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        bb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myTimer.cancel();
                myTimer.purge();
                myTimer = null;
                myTimer = new Timer("camerasTimer");
                Log.i("Check","[main]"+" timer stopped");
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reschedule a TimerTask. You need a new one every time. Moreover, it is advised in android to use Handlers and postDelayed.

Comment: hmmmm, but how can i schedule a repetitive task in handlers? it just delays a task, it doesn't set a period of time to run a new one after finishing the last one.

Comment: They usually call handler.postDelayed() again from the task itself. To cancel this periodic task they call handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages

Comment: hmmmm, ok then here's what I'm thinking, I'll lest the task itself call the handler.postDelay() just before it ends. is that a good design?

Comment: that's what i usually do. Also, you may consider using the AlarmManager if you need to schedule a repetitive task on the long term or if you need it to be ran if your application is not in the foreground (which does not appear to be the case here)

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, try to use Countdown timer instead of timer

quick usage:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

or if you want something more complex:

```
 public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
   public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
    super(startTime, interval);

  }
  @Override
   public void onFinish() {
   text.setText("Time's up!");
  }

  @Override
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
 text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution for you would be to use a Handler

```
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   handler = new Handler();
   runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
          // run code delayed code in here once
    }
};
```

Then in your multirepeating code you have to remove the posted callbacks and then reschedule for execution.

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200);
```